# Use Hunspell to check HTML in Aptana Studio?

Tags: html, eclipse, spell-checking, aptana3, hunspell

I have Aptana Studio 3 (build: 3.4.3.201308090259) with the Hunspell Eclipse plugin (version    0.8.7.201205281622). Spell checking is enabled in the preferences. Misspelled words are highlighted in comment blocks and some other places (which is, I believe, the default behavior).

Misspelled words are *not*, however, highlighted in HTML elements. For example, the following is not flagged:

<p>Mispelled</p>

Is there a way to turn on checking of HTML elements? I can find nothing in the Aptana/Eclipse preferences to specify which things are checked and which are not. I'm not averse to digging down into some plugin's configuration file to change this, but I can't spot the right place to make a change.